# How to declare a symmetric relation in RDF?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl

I have two URIs and have to connect them using a relation if they have any common substring.
This relation would be symmetric. How do I define this relation using RDF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In plain RDF, you can simply do this:

```
  my:relation a my:SymmetricRelation .
```

This expresses that the relation `my:relation` is of type `my:SymmetricRelation`.

However, if you also want a reasoner (such as an OWL reasoner) to do "clever things" with the fact that your relation is symmetric, then plain RDF is not really enough, and you'll need to switch to OWL, and model your relation as an `owl:SymmetricProperty`.

```
  my:relation a owl:SymmetricProperty .
```

Comment: In plain RDF, you can also do this: `my:relation a owl:SymmetricProperty .` It works as well as what your first example, and if presented to an OWL processor, magic happens.

Comment: Antoine, that's true of course, but I was trying to make a point (admittedly poorly) about the difference between _expressing_ knowledge and _interpreting_ knowledge.